# SO module found by Cython not found by Python3

Tags: python, import, module, cython

I have a simple `pyx` file:

```
$ cat helloworld.pyx
print("hello world in pyx file to be converted to so file by cython.")
```

I have created an `.so` module using Cython. The directory contains following files:

```
$ ls -ltrh
total 140K
-rw-r--r-- 1 cardio cardio  177 Jul  3  2018 setup.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 cardio cardio   73 Jul  3  2018 helloworld.pyx
-rw-r--r-- 1 cardio cardio  74K Jul  3  2018 helloworld.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cardio cardio  52K Jul  3  2018 helloworld.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 cardio cardio 4.0K Sep 10 20:21 __pycache__
```

However, when I try to import this module, I get error:

```
$ python3 -c "import helloworld"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

**Edit:**
The .so file was created in 2018! On recreating it again, everything is working perfectly! Probably there was some version conflict between Cython and Python.

Comment: Just to be sure: you are running the `python3` command in the same directory as the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commonly the reason why you can't import a module is that python doesn't see it in the location it is looking at `sys.path`.

You can verify this by going to the same location as the produced helloworld module, or by including it in the paths by force `sys.path.insert(0,os.getcwd())` can be a `current directory` or a `relative/absolute path`.

I seem to notice a `setup.py`, have you tried installing this with `pip install .` while being in that folder, after which trying to use it?

Comment: The `.so` file was created in 2018! On recreating it again, everything is working  perfectly! Probably there  was some version conflict between Cython and Python.